# Some location data from telemetry data are getting moved after adding CRS

Tags: r, mapview

I have movement data (shp file) downloaded from MoveBank. It is being plotted perfect in ArcGIS Pro and in R just by plotting the shp file. But for my analysis, I am adding a CRS to the data and projecting it. Then I used Mapview to check the data on the map and I found the locations after a certain longitude (at the western boundary) are being moved and being mapped on much eastern side as shown in the pictures. And the subsequent analysis also gave the wrong result.
I have used readOGR, shapefile and read_sf function separately to read the shp file. Everytime the problem remains same.[image]

Comment: What coordinate system are you defining and projecting to? What software are you using to project the data?

Comment: I am doing it in R

sp.UTM <- SpatialPoints(cbind(dat$utm_east, dat$utm_north), 
                        proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:32644")) 

sp.latlong <- spTransform(sp.UTM,
                          CRS("+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"))

# now lets check where our points land on the map
mapview(sp.latlong)

Comment: I'm not familiar with R but it looks like you're projecting from WGS84 UTM 44 North to WGS84 geographic, that should be easy. If you have access to ArcGIS Pro try using that to project the data and see if you get the same results. Is your data straddling the zone boundary? (78 degrees East)

Comment: yes, it is straddling. 
I tried your method too, it is not solving the problem.

Comment: That is extremely odd, can you share (a sample of) the data or the URL you used to obtain the data if it's free to download. How does the data look when viewed in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Thank you Michael. But I am not authorized right now to share this data. I will get back to you if I get permission. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelStimson see if this helps for now. If I select UTM values from my data then this problem occurs, but if I work with the geographic data the Mapview shows correct mapping. Anyhow, in both the process the subsequent results are wrong.

Comment: It sounds like mapview is wrapping the data to fit in the UTM zone extent and won't let you have records outside the zone, you could confirm that by viewing the data with ArcGIS Pro (or QGIS). If that's the case you may need to choose another projected coordinate system, Lamberts Conformal Conic or Albers Equal Area might be a good compromise depending on what kind of analysis you're trying to perform, EPSG:7766 perhaps?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I think you are right. And I am calculating total distance and average daily distance covered from the telemetry data. I need the projection in UTM since the calculation is done in meter. If you can tell me any method of doing it in ArcGIS Pro I can do it there as well.

Comment: EPSG:7766 units are metres, provided that mapview supports that projection it would be a reasonable compromise. I can't give advice on how to do your calcs in ArcGIS because I know nothing about how you're calculating average daily distance. That would be diverging from your original question and worthy of a new question (as per the site rules).

Comment: @MichaelStimson I tried this. It is projected in a distorted manner.

Comment: That's expected, a different projection will seem distorted when, in reality, it's just another way to view the data. Is the data so distorted that it is unusable? Given there is no problem with your data I think that you've uncovered a bug in mapview, you could add a bug report on https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues. The only other way I can think of is to divide your data into two datasets by the zone edge and project one in EPSG:32643 and the other in EPSG:32644.